# When writing an Eclipse's quick fix processor plug-in, what is the method "hasCorrections" for?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

In order to write a quick fix processor plug-in for Eclipse, ones have to write a class that implements the [`IQuickFixProcessor` interface](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/text/java/IQuickFixProcessor.html) and overrides its two method: `getCorrections` and `hasCorrections`.

I have successfully written the codes in `getCorrections` and got the quick fix utility to work, but I have no clue what should I write in `hasCorrections`.

My prior guess is that if it return `false`, it indicates that the processor have no proposal to fix the current problem and otherwise if `true`. And consequently, I expected that upon setting it to return `false`, my quick fix proposal will not be shown when the problem occurs, but it is not the case: there is no different no matter it return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is a bit hard to read but it looks like it is used when the quick fix code wants to know if anything has corrections, if something does have corrections it calls everything to get the corrections. If nothing has corrections it does not ask for the corrections.

Source is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.JavaCorrectionProcessor`